# How to give ALL special characters their literal meaning in re.search?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to figure out if the manufacturer/brand owner is selling a product on an online platform. For example, for a product with the brand name “Hello Olly”, I would like the following seller names to show a match

- HELlo ollY
- HelloOlly Inc.
- The hello olly Company

But not a Match for,

- XYZ Seller
- Hello **The** olly company

**Problem**: I run into problems where the brand name has special characters, such as (

**Goal**: To treat all special characters as literal strings. For example,

- ‘Hello (olly’   should show a match with ‘The Hello (olly Company’

  - Would be extra nice, if it also matches ‘Hello olly Company’ – note ( has been removed in seller name.
- ‘Hello (olly)’   should show a match with ‘The Hello (olly) Company’ – note the first instance had only opening (. This has both (). Having just ( in the product name creates extra complications, if there isn’t a matching closing bracket.

All of these problems should be resolved if special characters are treated as literal strings.

**Note**: There could be an arbitrary number of special characters at any position. I would like them all to have their literal meaning.

The following function works if there are no special characters. I tried to use re.escape() to deal with special characters, but it didn’t help

```
def match_string(brand, seller):
   
    brand = str(brand).lower().replace(" ", "") .replace("-", "") # may not need replace("-", "") if I have a better process to deal with all special characters.
    seller = str(seller).lower().replace(" ", "") .replace("-", "")

    # Tried the following two lines to give special characters their literal meaning. But it doesn't seem to work
    brand = re.escape(brand)
    seller = re.escape(seller)
    
    try:
        match = re.search(brand, seller).group()
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

THANKS, everyone

Comment: If you want to search for a literal substring, then what is the point of using regex? What is wrong with e.g. `brand in seller`?

Comment: Agreed with @KarlKnechtel 's proposed solution, why not use `brand.lower() in Seller.lower()`? This would always return if the brand was inside of the seller string.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Of course, it worked. I was making it too complicated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to us just `regex` or just "standard" string-manipulation and not mix them (could be hat it is just my personal preference). You could set the `re.IGNORECASE` flag to avoid casting everything to `str.lowercase()` first.

Now, the straight forward way would be to actually feed a regex-pattern to your function. In your example, it would be `'Hello\s?\(?olly\)?(\s?(Inc\.?)|(Company)|(Comp\.))?’'`. You could of course only look for `'Hello\s?\(?olly'` which would also return a match in all cases but not returns the part `'Hello (olly'` if the input string yould be `'The Hello (olly) Company)'`.

Howevery, I fear that you are trying to write a function that builds a regex pattern from an input string. That is difficult as it needs quite a few assumptions. The problem with constructing regex-patterns programatically is that is that python automatically adds escape characters to escape the escape characters that you want to use in the pattern.

That is why you get a

> re.error: bad escape \s at position 0
> error when using `re.sub(' +', '\s', text)`

or `r'(\(|\[|\{)?'` will look like

> '(\(|\[|\{)?'

I never thought of how to avoid this tough...

BTW, the return value of `re.search(brand, seller, re.IGNORECASE)` can be interpreted as a boolean:

```py
if re.search(brand, seller, re.IGNORECASE):
    print('I found the pattern!')
else:
    print('I did not found the pattern =(')
```